# Storing encryption key on ESP32

Tags: arduino, esp32

I am currently using Arduino IDE with ESP32. I would like to store encryption key on the ESP32. Where and how should I store it? Any examples would help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using EEPROM

Comment: Can a hacker get access to the EEPROM, extract the keys and then decode all the data?

Comment: Hacker can do that. What you can do is to make hacker more difficult to hack, because ESP32 doesn't have Hardware Secure Environment, so you can't certainly prevent such kind of hack. One of the easy techniques you can do is to apply XOR operator to mask your saved data